# Is there somewhere I can get a database of satellite catalog IDs and their friendly names?

Tags: satellites

I'm working on a program for ham radio that involves displaying satellites. I'm currently using the Space-track.org database, but the problem with it is that it will give "Saudisat 1C" rather than SO-50, and things like that. Is there a downloadable database that has a friendly name and its corresponding catalog ID?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Please consider taking [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.  73!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SatNOGS DB](https://db.satnogs.org/) records multiple names for satellites; for example, it has [both names you mention](https://db.satnogs.org/satellite/27607/). There is [a simple HTTP API](https://db.satnogs.org/api/) which you can use to fetch the entire database in JSON.

The database also includes downlink/uplink information (frequencies, mode, etc). It does not include orbital elements (TLEs), which you will have to obtain from another source by cross-referencing the catalog numbers.

I'm not enough of a satellite enthusiast to say how complete or accurate SatNOGS DB is; I do know it is a relatively new project and they are accepting contributions.

Answer (score 0):

PyEphem, a library to calculate (relative) positions of celestial bodies, has a [link page](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/catalogs) that lists digital catalogues you can, at least partially directly import.